# Querying from Soda database using Socrata client.get in Python

Tags: python, socrata, soda

I am trying to query from a database and I've tried to lookup the right way to format an SoQL string but I am failing. I try the following:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from sodapy import Socrata
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


client = Socrata("data.cityofchicago.org", None)

df = client.get("kkgn-a2j4", query="WHERE traffic > -1")
```

and receive an error that it `Could not parse SoQL query "WHERE traffic > -1" at line 1 character 1`. If I do the following, however, it works:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from sodapy import Socrata
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


client = Socrata("data.cityofchicago.org", None)

df = client.get("kkgn-a2j4", where="traffic > -1")
```

But I want to know how to get the query argument to work so I can use more complex queries. Specifically, I want to try to query when `traffic > -1` and `BETWEEN '2013-01-19T23:50:32.000' AND '2014-12-14T23:50:32.000'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sodapy `where` parameter (`$where` in SoQl) to combine multiple filters, just use `AND` to combine them:

`traffic > -1 AND last_update BETWEEN '2013-01-19T23:50:32.000' AND '2014-12-14T23:50:32.000'`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know how you would write the query string to obtain the same result?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed this one! You could write the `$query` as: `SELECT * WHERE traffic > -1 AND last_update BETWEEN '2013-01-19T23:50:32.000' AND '2014-12-14T23:50:32.000'`